# Error when trying to bind the visibleProperty of a TableColumn with a booleanProperty of another control

Tags: binding, javafx-8

I need to bind the visibleProperty of a TableColumn with a booleanProperty another control (selectedProperty of a ToggleButton, e.g.). Using the jdk1.8.0_40 was functioning normally, but using jdk1.8.0_60 started to receive the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: Bidirectional binding failed, setting to the previous value
at com.sun.javafx.binding.BidirectionalBinding$BidirectionalBooleanBinding.changed(BidirectionalBinding.java:284)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.BidirectionalBinding$BidirectionalBooleanBinding.changed(BidirectionalBinding.java:227)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty.setValue(BooleanProperty.java:77)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.setValue(BooleanPropertyBase.java:49)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.BidirectionalBinding.bind(BidirectionalBinding.java:64)
at javafx.beans.binding.Bindings.bindBidirectional(Bindings.java:757)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty.bindBidirectional(BooleanProperty.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableHeaderRow.createMenuItem(TableHeaderRow.java:523)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableHeaderRow.rebuildColumnMenu(TableHeaderRow.java:489)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableHeaderRow.updateTableColumnListeners(TableHeaderRow.java:462)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableHeaderRow.lambda$new$82(TableHeaderRow.java:254)
at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
at javafx.collections.FXCollections$UnmodifiableObservableListImpl.lambda$new$52(FXCollections.java:929)
at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:164)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.setAll(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:90)
at javafx.scene.control.TableView.updateVisibleLeafColumns(TableView.java:1634)
at javafx.scene.control.TableView.lambda$new$38(TableView.java:760)
at javafx.beans.WeakInvalidationListener.invalidated(WeakInvalidationListener.java:83)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:349)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.access$000(BooleanPropertyBase.java:49)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase$Listener.invalidated(BooleanPropertyBase.java:245)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
at javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton.setSelected(ToggleButton.java:149)
at javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton.fire(ToggleButton.java:255)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: TableColumn.visible : A bound value cannot be set.
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:140)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.BidirectionalBinding$BidirectionalBooleanBinding.changed(BidirectionalBinding.java:264)
... 76 more
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: Bidirectional binding failed, setting to the previous value
at com.sun.javafx.binding.BidirectionalBinding$BidirectionalBooleanBinding.changed(BidirectionalBinding.java:284)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.BidirectionalBinding$BidirectionalBooleanBinding.changed(BidirectionalBinding.java:227)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.BidirectionalBinding$BidirectionalBooleanBinding.changed(BidirectionalBinding.java:266)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.BidirectionalBinding$BidirectionalBooleanBinding.changed(BidirectionalBinding.java:227)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:361)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.access$000(BooleanPropertyBase.java:49)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase$Listener.invalidated(BooleanPropertyBase.java:245)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
at javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton.setSelected(ToggleButton.java:149)
at javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton.fire(ToggleButton.java:255)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: TableColumn.visible : A bound value cannot be set.
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:140)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.BidirectionalBinding$BidirectionalBooleanBinding.changed(BidirectionalBinding.java:264)
... 53 more
```

Sample code (based on Ensemble8 application):

```
public class TableViewApp extends Application {

public Parent createContent() {
    final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Person("Jacob",     "Smith",    "jacob.smith@example.com" ),
        new Person("Isabella",  "Johnson",  "isabella.johnson@example.com" ),
        new Person("Ethan",     "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com" ),
        new Person("Emma",      "Jones",    "emma.jones@example.com" ),
        new Person("Michael",   "Brown",    "michael.brown@example.com" )
    );
    TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn();
    firstNameCol.setText("First");
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));
    TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn();
    lastNameCol.setText("Last");
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("lastName"));
    TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn();
    emailCol.setText("Email");
    emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
    emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("email"));
    TableView tableView = new TableView();
    tableView.setItems(data);
    tableView.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

    ToggleButton toggleButton = new ToggleButton("Visible lastNameCol");
    toggleButton.setSelected(true);

    lastNameCol.visibleProperty().bind(toggleButton.selectedProperty()); // Error

    VBox parent = new VBox(10);

    parent.getChildren().addAll(toggleButton,tableView);

    return parent;
}

@Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * Java main for when running without JavaFX launcher
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Class Person for example:

```
public class Person {
private StringProperty firstName;
private StringProperty lastName;
private StringProperty email;

public Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
    this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
    this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
    this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
}

public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
    return firstName;
}

public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
    return lastName;
}

public StringProperty emailProperty() {
    return email;
}
}
```

I searched for a reported bug but found, someone is going through the same problem?

Comment: That looks like a bug. I think it's caused by the table menu button; if you call `tableView.setTableMenuButtonVisible(true);` you will notice that the check boxes in that menu are not updating correctly. Obviously as a workaround you can just use a listener...

Comment: I experienced the same problem in large JavaFX application we are developing. We used 1.8.0_31 - no problem, but 1.8.0_60 had the problem. We had a button in the table header which expanded/collapsed 4 more columns. The error then runs ad infinitum. Did you report the bug?

Comment: OK - so I found it reported as a bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8136468